# Unable to rename the column in hudi table on AWS glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, aws-glue, apache-hudi

I am getting an error  while I was trying to renaming the column in hudi table

```
%etl
%session_id_prefix native-hudi-dataframe-
%glue_version 3.0
%idle_timeout 2880
%worker_type G.2X
%number_of_workers 20
%%configure 
{
    "--conf": "spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer --conf spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog --conf spark.sql.legacy.pathOptionBehavior.enabled= true --conf spark.sql.extensions= org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension",
    "--datalake-formats": "hudi",
    "--enable-metrics": "true",
    "--enable-spark-ui": "true",
    "--spark-event-logs-path": "s3://aws-glue-assets-441369475256-us-west-1/sparkHistoryLogs/",
    "--enable-job-insights": "true",
    "--enable-glue-datacatalog": "true",
    "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": "true",
    "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-disable"
}



import logging
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
  
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
logger = glueContext.get_logger()





db_name = "dev_mesh"
table_name_test = "data_quality_pass_results"
query = f"ALTER TABLE {db_name}.{table_name_test} RENAME COLUMN PartialPaymentLetterOfExpalnDate TO PartialPaymentLetterOfExplanDate"
spark.sql(query)
print(f"Query Executed: {query}")

print_hudi_table(BUCKET=BUCKET)
```

`

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o97.sql.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot find catalog plugin class for catalog 'spark_catalog': org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog
at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.Catalogs$.load(Catalogs.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.loadV2SessionCatalog(CatalogManager.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.$anonfun$v2SessionCatalog$2(CatalogManager.scala:85)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.$anonfun$v2SessionCatalog$1(CatalogManager.scala:85)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.v2SessionCatalog(CatalogManager.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.catalog(CatalogManager.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.currentCatalog(CatalogManager.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.LookupCatalog.currentCatalog(LookupCatalog.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.LookupCatalog.currentCatalog$(LookupCatalog.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs.currentCatalog(ResolveCatalogs.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.LookupCatalog$CatalogAndIdentifier$.unapply(LookupCatalog.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.LookupCatalog$NonSessionCatalogAndIdentifier$.unapply(LookupCatalog.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs$NonSessionCatalogAndTable$.unapply(ResolveCatalogs.scala:220)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(ResolveCatalogs.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(ResolveCatalogs.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:221)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators(AnalysisHelper.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators$(AnalysisHelper.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs.apply(ResolveCatalogs.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs.apply(ResolveCatalogs.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:216)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:118)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:205)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:196)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:190)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:228)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:163)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:163)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:71)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:97)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:615)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:610)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
`